# GMaps v3: addDomListener mouseenter event handling not working on Chrome, Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

Is this a bug in the google maps API?

If I use the prototype library to add the mouseenter, and mouseleave event handlers, it works just fine.  [But if I use addDomListener, it doesn't work.](http://devservices.northcarolina.edu/lcl/ded_unco/exams/test_suite/mouseenter2.html)  Although it works in Firefox, the event handling function never gets called in Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Maps API for adding event handlers to the Map, or other API objects.

**Example with Map Enter/Out:**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mouseover", function() {
  // Mouse Entered the Map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mouseout", function() {
  // Mouse Left the Map
});
```

[Maps API Reference Guide - Scroll to Events for the Map to See All Map Event Options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Comment: Ok, those were the events I was looking for.  Don't know how I got them confused with mouseenter and mouseleave.